# Timer added with scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval works fine with UI interaction

Tags: swift, foundation

I've scheduled the timer with `scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.008`
and it is going on despite the user interaction. This **IS** the behavior
that I want but this article
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer
implied that it won't/doesn't work. But it does for me.

This is on iOS 16.1 simulator.

So do I still need runLoop/CADisplayLink mode .common or this somehow works on recent iOSes by .default if you pardon the pun.

Upd: I've resolved this for myself switching to CADisplayLink mode .common since that is more efficient than firing timer 120 times per second anyway but the question still stands why NSTimer fired in .default mode with UI interaction in progress.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking why your app is working as you want it to?

Comment: Yes, in .default mode it should not. At least that's what the fairly up to date article says. Maybe I'm not testing this right and with some UI input timer fails to fire.

Comment: Well your question is unclear, not only what you are actually asking about but there is also no code example and could explain better what part of the linked article you refer to for example by quoting from it.

Comment: yeah. In the docs, default runLoop will change to traking. But I can't test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer) the `scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, block: @escaping @Sendable (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer`:

> Creates a timer and schedules it on the current run loop in the
> default mode.

So it uses the same run loop as the main thread, if the main thread is busy processing user input events then the timer events will not be executed. To reproduce this you can tap on a tableview and start scrolling, until you lift your finger the timer will not fire. The information from the [guide](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer) seems to be correct.

Comment: I do not have tableview there but I guess that would explain some lag I saw there once during UI interaction.